# How to consume wsdl web service by using a certificate in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, soap, wsdl

I am working on a windows phone 8 application, Client has provided me a wsdl url and a certificate with ".cert" extension. By using add service reference, i am adding wsdl web service. Now how to use this service and where to use the certificate, i am not getting. Anyone please tell me after adding service reference what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 does not support client certificate. You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402533) out for more details.